# No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification] with root cause

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, specifications

I want to implement Spring application which servers tables with pages:

```
[HPM] GET /api_admin/transactions/find?page=0&size=10
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("find")
    public Page<PaymentTransactionsDTO> getAllBySpecification(
            @And({
                    @Spec(path = "uniqueId", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                    @Spec(path = "createdAt", params = "from", spec = GreaterThanOrEqual.class, config="uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"),
                    @Spec(path = "createdAt", params = "to", spec = LessThanOrEqual.class, config="uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
            }) Specification<Transactions> specification,
            @SortDefault(sort = "createdAt", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable
    ) {        
        return transactionService.getAllBySpecification(specification, pageable)
                  .map(g -> TransactionsDTO.builder()                     
                            .id(g.getId()) 
                            ..............
                            .build()
                    );       
    }
```

Spring Repository:

```
public Page<PaymentTransactions> getAllBySpecification(final Specification<PaymentTransactions> specification, final Pageable pageable) {
        return this.dao.findAll(specification, pageable);
}
```

I'm trying to use this framework in order to implement the search functionality: https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver

I get error:

```
00:24:27.335 [http-nio-8020-exec-4] ERROR [dispatcherServlet][log:175] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api_admin] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification.<init>()
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue? I was working fine when I used Spring deployed into JBoss container but now I can this exception when I use Spring Standalone application.

Full error log: https://pastebin.com/4j0sqTjr

Comment: Do you add SpecificationArgumentResolver to argumentResolvers according to spec?
https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver#enabling-spec-annotations-in-your-spring-app

Comment: Yes,.. this was the issue by mistake I remove it. Please paste official answer so that I can rate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the spec](https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver#enabling-spec-annotations-in-your-spring-app), SpecificationArgumentResolver should be added to argumentResolvers

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new SpecificationArgumentResolver());
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: or just declare `@Bean public HandlerMethodArgumentResolver specificationArgumentResolver() { return new SpecificationArgumentResolver(); } ` in any `@Configuration` class

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import net.kaczmarzyk.spring.data.jpa.web.SpecificationArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argument Resolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new SpecificationArgumentResolver());
    }

}
```